# Quotient group of $S^3$ by a cyclic group is always a lens space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, group-actions, geometric-topology

By definition, for coprime integers $p,q$, the lens space $L(p,q)$ is a quotient space of $S^3$ by the $\Bbb Z_p$-action generated by $(z,w)\mapsto (e^{2\pi i/p}z, e^{2\pi i q /p}w)$.

On the other hand, we can regard $S^3=SU(2)$ as a Lie group, and $S^3$ has cyclic subgroups of all orders. Is it true that, for any integer $p>1$ and any cyclic subgroup $G\subset S^3$ of order $p$, the quotient space $S^3/G$ is homeomorphic to $L(p,q)$ for some $q$? (Maybe this should be easy if I know all cyclic subgroups of $S^3$ of order $p$, which I don't know.)

Comment: You need bits and pieces from linear algebra. Let $A\in SU(2)$ be a generator of your cyclic group. It is Hermitian so diagonalizable. If it has order $p$, then what might its eigenvalues be? Replace $A$ with a suitable power to adjust one of the eigenvalues...

Comment: Oh, and if you replace $A$ with a conjugate why does that lead to a homeomorphic quotient space.

Comment: Mind you, this question may have been handled here already. Possibly in some purely algebraic guise. Try to work with the "hints" I don't have the time to search now.